# XML Minify in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, minify

I'd like to read in the following XML:

```
<node></node>
```

And then write it out, minified, like this:

```
<node/>
```

Obviously this has the same meaning, but the second file is smaller for sending across the wire.

I'm trying to find a way to do this in .NET. I can't seem to find an option or setting that would drop unnecessary closing tags.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use LINQ to XML, you can call `XElement.RemoveNodes()` which will convert it to the second form. So something like this:

```
var emptyTags = doc.Descendants().Where(x => !x.Nodes().Any()).ToList();

foreach (XElement tag in emptyTags)
{
    tag.RemoveNodes();
}
```

Then save the document in the normal way, and I *think* it will do what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the XML into a new structure.

```
public static XElement Minify(XElement element) {
    return new XElement(element.Name, element.Attributes(),
        element.Nodes().Select(node => {
            if (node is XElement)
                return Minify((XElement)node);
            return node;
        })
    );
}
```

Here is another solution but LINQ-less http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/e1e881db-6547-42c4-b379-df5885f779be

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Load("input.xml");
foreach (XmlElement el in 
   doc.SelectNodes("descendant::*[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]"))
{
  el.IsEmpty = true;
}
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the XmlElement [IsEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty.aspx) property.

Comment: IsEmpty will only tell me if the node has children or not. If I set it to true - it will drop child elements.

Comment: Don't set it to true for nodes that contain children, but if you set it to true for empty nodes then they would be serialized using the short format.

Comment: so:

if (x.IsEmpty) x.IsEmpty = true;

? that seems a bit wrong.

Comment: Looks like Bob found something that uses this property in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this myself, but have you tried experimenting with the XmlWriter's [XmlWriterSettings.OutputMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.outputmethod.aspx) Property?

The following page gives you the options you can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmloutputmethod.aspx

Comment: I don't think that this will help, unless "Serialize according to the XML 1.0 rules." means to drop the empty end tags.  I will try this out as an example though.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [WebMarkupMin XML Minifier](http://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com) with the option "Collapse tags without content":

```
    const string xmlInput = "<row RoleId=\"4\" RoleName=\"Administrator\"></row>\n" +
        "<row RoleId=\"5\" RoleName=\"Contributor\"></row>\n" +
        "<row RoleId=\"6\" RoleName=\"Editor\"></row>"
        ;

    var xmlMinifier = new XmlMinifier(
        new XmlMinificationSettings{ CollapseTagsWithoutContent = true });

    MarkupMinificationResult result = xmlMinifier.Minify(xmlInput);

    Console.WriteLine("Minified content:{0}{0}{1}",
        Environment.NewLine, result.MinifiedContent);
```